# When sqlite_* functions will be updated to use SQLite ver. 3

Tags: php, sqlite

When Rasmus Lerdorf will update sqlite_* functions here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php to use SQLite version 3?

I know I can use PDO. I want to use the native functions since they are faster. And no, I don't want database abstraction.

I'm using PHP 5.3 and the database that was created using SQLite 2.8.17. Here's my code:

```
if ($db = sqlite_open('whatever', 0666, $sqliteerror)){ 
    sqlite_query($db, 'CREATE TABLE foo (bar varchar(10))');
    sqlite_query($db, "INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('fnord')");
    $result = sqlite_query($db, 'select bar from foo');
    var_dump(sqlite_fetch_array($result)); 
} else {
    die($sqliteerror);
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's Rasmus himself working on the SQLite PHP module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has a separate [SQLite3 extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php). It's right below the original SQLite extension in the manual menu in case you didn't notice.

The original SQLite extension is probably still there for backward compatibility.